# Proving Monotone of $\cos(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis

How can we show that $\cos(x)\geq0$ whenever $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ where $\cos(x)$ is represented by its infinite series representation?

Comment: What is your definition of $ \cos x $?

Comment: the infinite series representation

Comment: your question involves $\pi$, so another question: what's your defintion of $\pi$?  There's several ways to define this constant, say the path integral of the unit circle, or using FitzPatrick's Advanced Calculus's definition : minimal $p > 0$ so that $C(p/2) = 0$, where $C'(x) = S(x)$ and $S(x) = -C'(x)$ are "ode"s.  Your infinite series definition suit well these two ODEs, as the radius of convergence is $+\infty$.

Comment: $\pi$ is nothing but the double of the value of the infimum of $x$ belonging to interval $[0,2]$ such that $\cos(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos$ is continuous and $\cos(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ using your definition of $\pi$, thus $\cos(x)>0$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ or $\cos(x)<0$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Since $\cos(0)=1>0$, we have $\cos(x)>0$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.